# How to write an array object/element to a table in Javascript

Tags: javascript, arrays, html-table

My title for this question may not be using the correct terminology but here is what I would like to do. (I am still new to Javascript so im looking for a basic method)

First my table has to be created using Javascript,
then I need to take an array object/element and "write" it to a table cell.

I say "write" because I'm not sure if that's the correct word to use.

Here is an example of the code I'm working with:

```
<script type="text/javascript">
/* <![CDATA[ */

var day = [];
day[0] = "monday"

document.write("<table>")
document.write("<tr><td>"**what syntax do i use to insert the data for "day[0]" here**"</td></tr>")
document.write("</table>")

/* ]]> */
</script>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

try

```
<script type="text/javascript">
/* <![CDATA[ */

var day = [];
day[0] = "monday";

document.write("<table>")
document.write("<tr><td>" + day[0] + "</td></tr>")
document.write("</table>")

/* ]]> */
</script>
```

also you don't have to declare the array like

```
var day = [];
day[0] = "monday";
```

you can simply do

```
var day = ["monday"];
```